# Rename File before Storing in Server PHP

Tags: php, android

I need to know code how to rename file before it gets uploaded to my server in php script.Ill post the php code of mine.

I need it because I am uploading an image from phone and I don't want it to be overwritten.

Can I achieve that?

```
<?php

$file_path = "uploads/";

$file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
    echo "success";
} else{
    echo "fail";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For renaming file in Android, you can do :

```
String file_path = <file path off your existing file you want to rename>
File from = new File(file_path,"from.txt");
File to = new File(file_path,"to.txt");
from.renameTo(to);
```

This code will work for both file stored in internal or external storage. Just for writing to external storage remember you need to have android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE to be added to your Android manifest.

Comment: Yeah i know this code.But you see its an app which captures picture so imagine million people capturing it.So i can't stand on exact i just need on random one.Wait!on line File to can i put a code which will be generated random ally?

Comment: surely you can unify the file naming using user_id + currenttimemillies or some other logic

Answer (score 0):

write your code like below.

```
    $filename = $_FILES['upload_file']['name'];
    $newname = 'alteredtext'.$filename; // you can also generate random number and concat on start.
    $tmp_path = $_FILES['upload_file']['tmp_name'];
    if(move_uploaded_file($mp_path, $newname)) {
        echo "success";
    } else{
       echo "fail";
    }
```

Comment: Let me see..but you pointing to exact file on first line right??but i need php to scan and after see like oh wow i got duplicate.And afterwards not to overwrite it just to generate random name.Hows possible?

Comment: then what you can do is check the newly created filename in the directory whether the file exist or not if not then continue uploading if you want me to right the code for that let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the name passed in the $_FILES array when moving the file.  You can create any name you want (assuming the path is valid) and pass it as the second argument of move_uploaded_file.  If you want a semi-random name, you could generate a random number and then hash it or something to create the filename.

If you want to check first, if the file exists, then rename it to have a numeric suffix, you could do this:

```
<?php

$base_path = "uploads/";

$file_path = $base_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
if(file_exists($file_path)) {
    $ctr = 0;
    do { // increment an index to append to the filepath
        $ctr++;
        $file_path = $base_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']) . "_$ctr";
    } while(file_exists($file_path));
}

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
    echo "success";
} else{
    echo "fail";
}
?>
```

The above snippet will keep incrementing until it finds a filename that doesn't exist.  Of course, you'd want to add some bounds and error checking, while the above snippet demonstrates the concept, it isn't entirely production ready.

Comment: you gave me good hint ill try to understand what you mainly say and achieve that